# bash evaluate similar in scala

Tags: scala

I have a string which contains `${variable1}` and `${variable2}` in the string for example.

```
"select * from table where product ='${variable1}' and name='${variable2}'"
```

I can evaluate the string in bash in run time using eval.

```
export variable1="iphone"
export variable2="apple"
sql_query=`eval echo ${sql_query}`
```

which then turns the `select * from table where product='iphone' and name='apple'`

How to achieve the same in scala? At the moment I am using string replace function.

Is there any other way of doing this? Is there eval in scala?

Comment: Manually quoting parameter in SQL statement, whatever is the lang, is a cause for SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done but you have to dig into the string interpolation details.

```
val input="select * from table where product='${variable1}' and name='${variable2}'"

val variable1 = "iphone"
val variable2 = "apple"

val sql_query = StringContext(input.split("\\$[^}]+}"): _*).s(variable1,variable2)
//sql_query: String = select * from table where product='iphone' and name='apple'
```

Note that for this to work you have to know, in advance, which variables, and how many, are referenced in the input string.

---

**UPDATE**

Judging from your comments it's apparent that you are new to writing code. You also haven't described your situation and requirements very well. Perhaps due to lack of experience with written English.

I'm guessing that you want to replace referenced variable name with `String`  values found in the current shell environment.

Maybe something like this.

```
val exampleStr = "blah '${HOME}' blah '${SHELL}' blah '${GLOB}' blah"

val pattern = "\\$\\{([^}]+)}".r

pattern.replaceAllIn(exampleStr, s =>
                     System.getenv.getOrDefault(s.group(1),"unknown"))
//res0: String = blah '/home/me' blah '/bin/bash' blah 'unknown' blah
```

Comment: we have to variables in advance , but in bash I dont need is there no other alternative way of doing this ?

Comment: at the moment I am getting all system.getenv as key value pair and looping and replacing , it very slow as it need to check each and every variable ....

Comment: for ((k, v) <- System.getenv()) {
        if (getFromMeta(sc,sq,workFlow,compName,compParam,env,busDate,toEmail,fromEmail).toString.contains("'$" + "{" + s"$k" + "}'")) {
          evalResult = getFromMeta(sc,sq,workFlow,compName,compParam,env,busDate,toEmail,fromEmail).toString.replace("'$" + "{" + s"$k" + "}'", "'" + s"$v" + "'")
        }

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a feature that is called 'string interpolation' in Scala. Use the `s` prefix on Scala strings in order to enable string interpolation.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val variable1 = "iphone"
variable1: String = iphone

scala> val variable2 = "apple"
variable2: String = apple

scala> val sql_query = s"select * from table where product ='${variable1}' and name='${variable2}'"
sql_query: String = select * from table where product ='iphone' and name='apple'
```

Comment: imagine the sql (select * from table where product='${variable1}' and name='${variable2}' ) coming from a file as value , the sql in my case is not a string its a value I have to read from file.

Comment: val sql_query=getFromMetadata(function_arguments.....) , then sql_query variable has now value (select * from table where ${....}) etc ...., at the moment I am using replace function something like , getFromMetadata(function_arguments.....).replace("$", "").replace("{variable1}", iphone) for example

Comment: You did not state that the problem included reading the string from a file. Instead, you described a fixed string. Please accept this answer.

For your modified question, you just need to do string substitution, and the JVM gives you lots of options for that. If you need help on that please create a new question. I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: Also, please don't tag Scala questions as "Java".

Comment: I removed the "Java" tag